# jQuery Dialog UI scrolls to the top indefinably

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm working on someone's code and they used jquery UI Dialog for all the popups. The problem is that the page keeps scrolling to the top while the dialog is left wherever it was opened at. Here's the code:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[href$="#dialog"]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#contact-popup').dialog({
        title: 'Contact',
        modal: true,
        width: 328,
        show: {effect: 'fade', duration: 400},
        hide: {effect: 'fade', duration: 400},
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        open: function() {
            $('#contact-popup form').show();
            $('#thanks').hide();
        }
    })
    return false;
});
```

I've tried `e.preventDefault()`, `return false`, but it still scrolls to the top of the page.

I'm calling the dialog from an anchor: `<a href="#dialog">Click Here</a>`

Do I need to change the way I'm calling the dialog? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Here's the link so you can test it out: `test.persogenics.com/hire/interview-guide/`

Just tried putting the dialog 'open' into a regular js function - didn't work - still scrolls to the top:

```
js:
function popup() {
    $('#contact-popup').dialog()
    return false;
};

html:
<button onClick="popup();">Click Me</button>
```

this means it's not an anchor issue,.. right?

Comment: I'm thinking there's something else going on here. The prevent default will stop the page jump, and so will the return false. Any other code to speak of that may be involved?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - added another snippet of code that uses the same id - not sure if that is what you meant. Any help is appreciated

Comment: The page didn't scroll to the top for me... (using IE9)

Comment: @tymeJV - yes - forgot to mention that - it works fine in IE9 and Opera - but it scrolls to the top in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: This might be due to the appended modal window and not your click event.  I wasn't sure, but if I removed the absolute positioning of the modal background, it prevents the scrolling.

Comment: @xivo - which background? I've been changing a bunch of them from `absolute` to `relative` and can't seem to re-create what you meant

Comment: @tonylefler - The modal (slightly transparent) background -- your site has a js error currently.

Comment: @xivo - sorry - I was testing something out. It's fixed now. Also - I just deleted the `absolute positioning` on the div and it still pushes it to the top. Also, jQuery UI auto-adds a `position:relative;` to the div if there's no other style delegating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue! Turns out that the issue was an absolute positioned input I created to "trick" the dialog UI into not auto-focusing on any of the real inputs.

```
<div id="contact-popup" style="display:none">

--> <input type='text' style='position:absolute; top:-9999px;' />

    <form method="post" action="../../email.php">
        <h5>Leave us your contact info and we'll get in touch.</h5>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <input type="text" name="first-name" value="" class="required">
```

I guess that trips out the view of the page because it pushes it to the top.

Now I know that you not only have to be careful how you write the jQuery, but also what you put into the dialog popups!

Thank you to everyone for your help on this!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are using an anchor URL which points to an anchor within a page
common practice is passing "javascript:void(0)" as href, in your case you are detecting the particular anchor by it's href, so to tackle that you can pass a class to the anchor tags that point to the dialog box and selecting by that.
Maybe something like this

```
<a class="dialog_link" href="javascript:void(0)" >
```

and JQuery

```
$('body').on('click', ',dialog_link', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('#contact-popup').dialog({
    title: 'Contact',
    modal: true,
    width: 328,
    show: {effect: 'fade', duration: 400},
    hide: {effect: 'fade', duration: 400},
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    open: function() {
        $('#contact-popup form').show();
        $('#thanks').hide();
    }
})
return false;
```

});

Comment: I thought the same thing - but when you check the page source, there are no instances of a `id="dialog"` anywhere. And yes, I've tried `javascript:void(0)"` to no avail...